# How to deal with net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am including a JS library into my website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js "></script>
```

that is designed, maintained and hosted by a webdesign company.
The implementation of what I am trying to achieve seems to be well coded – see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvn_anakin/abnd3o0w/4/) – it works fine with no errors. However when a copy and paste the code from my JSfiddle into my website, it doesn’t work at all – Google Chrome developer console shows this:

`GET https://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

But it is weird, since my Jsfiddle code is including the same `turn.min.js` and it works there, but on my website it doesn’t.

Comment: `http://` works, `https://` doesn't.

Comment: In the fiddle you're including the file through `http://`, not `https://`. You need to fix your SSL certificate - assuming you have one. If you don't then you cannot use `https://`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan @robertklep Yes, I see now, but then I have that mixed error and getting the same result: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Where is that error coming from? That is caused by calling non-secured content (ie. `http://`) from a secure site (`https://`)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know what caused the error but how do i fixed it without manipulating with SSl certf. beacuse I have no direct access to it

Comment: You can't. If you don't have an SSL certificate setup on the domain you cannot use `https://`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Rory man look at what my Console displayed - it says that my website is loading over HTTPS but the JS script I am trying to load is insecure i.e. JS script is only HTTP → So is there any way how to fix this since it is obviously not my problem but problem of the JS script providers? Am I getting it right?

Comment: That's right. You could just copy the script and host it on your own domain instead though

Answer (score 18):

This is not a javascript problem, it's an ssl probem.

You can't get a file through an insecure connection (http) from a html page served through a secure connection (https). If you're going to use https (and you SHOULD!) then you need to get the script through a secure connection.
To get the file, you should use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js "></script>
```

And make sure that the file is being served through https, by configuring the server accordingly. Here's a simple configuration for [lighttpd](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToSimpleSSL), and here's one for [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html). If you don't have a CA signed certificate, you could get one with letsencrypt ( www.letsencrypt.org/getting-started/ ). If you don't control the server, you should get in contact with the person who does.

Answer (score 3):

- 1) http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js could not be reached through HTTPS. This causes your error.
- 2) JSfiddle accessed through HTTP hence no problems
- 3) `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js "></script>` will cause problems in any cases for your site, because this is an example of mixed content which will be blocked by almost all browsers.

## Solution:

Copy this file on your server and then include local version

I prefer include script to the pages in that way:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js "></script>`.

That allowed browser to check connection type itself. Which is actually won't work in you case (*see p.1*).

An very good explanation in [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)