# SSL error when connecting react to asp.net web api from localhost

Tags: .net, reactjs, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to connect a react project to an asp.net web api project,but im getting this error

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Answer (score 1):

From your vague question, I am assuming you are running the API on HTTPS and your react app is not.

Try not running your API on HTTPS.

Ref: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232686/how-to-deal-with-neterr-ssl-protocol-error)