# Websocket ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR over https

Tags: php, apache, ssl, websocket

I am using PHP at server side and APACHE webserver

If I use secure web socket protocol over HTTPS:

At client side I am using Javascript to connect websocket. Folllowing is the code
`

```
var wsUri = wss://mywebsite.com:8012/test/web-socket    
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
}`
```

I receive an error on establishing connection net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Same is working with http

Comment: are the two secured with the same certificate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with net::ERR\_SSL\_PROTOCOL\_ERROR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232686/how-to-deal-with-neterr-ssl-protocol-error)

Comment: no, because that link explaing to use js on https only. I am already using js over https.

Comment: the error is the same. the same reasons apply to the websocket connection

Comment: error is same, but reason mention into that tread is not applicable to my error. AT my end all links are getting served over https only.

Comment: also below setting is already present at my end:                                        <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by provided certificate & key compbined file to stream_context_set_option function. That resolved ssl_protocol_error.

```
$context = stream_context_create();         
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/tmp/combined_cert.pem');         
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');           
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);          
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
```