# How to get Amazon EC2 to accept https with socket.io

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, socket.io

My server works fine for http requests, but when I send https, I get:
polling-xhr.js:268 GET https://ec2-18-218-160-24.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N826ajA net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My security groups definitely allow http and https.  Any ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with net::ERR\_SSL\_PROTOCOL\_ERROR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232686/how-to-deal-with-neterr-ssl-protocol-error)

Comment: See "How to deal with net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?" answer